# How can i prevent editing a Parent object if it has been assigned to a child object in my asp.net MVc web application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

I have two objects:-

```
LabTest
LabTestDetails
```

Where a `LabTest` object can have zero or many `LabTestDetails` objects.
I need to implement the following business rule:-

*The user should not be able to edit a LabTest object if it has been assigned to one or more LabTestDetails objects.*

Currently i have implemented a helper method named `IsAlreadyAssigned` on the LabTest object (to check if the LabTest object has been assigned to any LabTestDetails object):-

```
public partial class LabTest 
    {    
public bool IsAlreadyAssigned(int id)
            {

                return (LabTestDetailss.Any(r2 => r2.LabTestID == id));

            }}
```

Then i have added the following checks on the `Get & Post` Edit action methods:-

```
  public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {


        LabTest c = repository.GetLabTest (id);

        if ((c == null) ||  (c.IsAlreadyAssigned (id)))
        {
            return View("Error");
        }

        return View(c);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection colletion)
    {

       LabTest c = repository.GetLabTest (id);
       if ((c == null) ||  (c.IsAlreadyAssigned (id))) // *******
        {
            return View("Error");
       }
        try
        {
            if (TryUpdateModel(c))
            {

                elearningrepository.Save();
                return RedirectToAction("Details", new { id = c.LabTestID });
            }
        }
```

The above might work fine on most of the cases, but if the `LabTest` object were just assigned to a labTestDetails object by another user after the `if ((c == null) ||  (c.IsAlreadyAssigned (id)))` check on the post action method i mark it as(*******) on the above code , then my business logic will be broken.

**so is there a way to implement my action methods so that it will always prevent editing a LabTest object if it has been assigned to a LabTestdetail object .**

BR

Comment: If you are using Linq to Sql or Entity Framework behind the scenes, then you might be able to do this with concurrency checking

Comment: i am using Entity Framework but it do not handle such situations; as this buisness rule is not implemented and can not be implemented at the database level.. so the EF will not be able to detect such senario.

Comment: You're saying it cannot be implemented at the database level? Are you open to using stored procs?

Comment: @MisterJames exactly what I was thinking

Comment: yes i can use stored procedures,, but how can i implement this buisness logic using stored procedure ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a stored procedure, as suggested in the comments, but you could also create a service method that checks whether or not a `LabTest` is assigned, like

```
public bool LabTestIsAssigned(int labTestId)
{
    using (var context = new YourContext())
    {
        return context.LabTestDetails.Any(d => d.LabTestID == id);
    }
}
```

The advantage of using this method, rather than the navigation property, is that it is guaranteed to reflect the current state of the database.

Note that you'll have to do this check just before saving changes as well! Even then, an insert may occur right after evaluating the check and just before saving the changes.

Comment: which means that using the service method will not guarantee 100% that the object is still not assigned yet!!! am i right?

Comment: Yes, that 's true. A stored procedure, where you can use locking, is the only possibility to make it watertight. Or you must update a LabTest record (with versioning) when you add or remove LabTestDetails in one transaction.